# minitest route testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I use minitest for testing framework. I try to test routes.

```
routes.rb

match "/auth/:provider/callback", to: "sessions#create", :as => sessioncallback
```

I want to test this route. I try a code like below:

```
assert_routing "/auth/:provider/callback", :controller => "sessions", :action => "create", "provider"=>"identity"
```

But I didn't get success from this routing test. It gives:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"create"}
```

I ran `rake routes` command. My routes like below:

```
    sessions GET     /sessions(.:format)                sessions#index
            POST     /sessions(.:format)                sessions#create
 new_session GET     /sessions/new(.:format)            sessions#new
edit_session GET     /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)       sessions#edit
     session GET     /sessions/:id(.:format)            sessions#show
             PUT     /sessions/:id(.:format)            sessions#update
          DELETE     /sessions/:id(.:format)            sessions#destroy
 sessioncallback     /auth/:provider/callback(.:format) sessions#create
```

How can i solve this? I wait your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the corresponding line in config/routes.rb

Comment: match "/auth/:provider/callback", to: "sessions#create", :as => sessioncallback. this is my route definiton on routes.rb

Comment: can you try with get instead of match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to substitute the :provider param in your route. Try this instead:

```
assert_routing "/auth/identity/callback", 
  :controller => "sessions",
  :action => "create",
  "provider"=>"identity"
```